# Ssh exit code not working within function

Tags: ssh, bash

So I have a function that looks like this. It's an oversimplified example but its enough to demonstrate my issue.

For some reason, I can not get the exit status of the ssh remote command. It does not matter if I give exit 0, or true or if I give a command that throws a success command, the end result is the same, I always get **1**.

The thing is, this code works perfectly when ran from a script, but not if I do it from a function.

```
function hello(){
      while read user password
      do
          ssh -n -q user@host 'exit 0' ; echo $?
      done <<< "$( cat creds.txt )"
}
```

Comment: This works for me and returns three `0`: `function hello { seq 1 3 | while read user password; do ssh -n -q localhost 'exit 0'; echo $?; done; }; hello`

Answer (score 2):

Remember that ssh doesn't allow to pass the password as an argument.
You will need to use an external utility like sshpass or public/private key.

With sshpass, the function will look like this:

```
function hello(){
      while read user host password
      do
          sshpass -p "$password" ssh -n -q $user@$host 'exit' ; echo $?
      done <<< "$( cat creds.txt )"
}
```

I tried the script with a list of 2 hosts; one with a good password and one with a bad password:

```
5 # result of a bad password
0 # result of a good password
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you want to do automation for Linux machines. It is time to start learning [ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)) or any other [configuration management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software).

Please read also about [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).